# how to query ManyToMany

Tags: django

```
    class Publication(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    class Article(models.Model):
        headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)


A1=>[P1,P2]
A2=>[P2,P3,P4]
```

How to get a queryset in all of the [P1,P2,P3,P4]
Article.all().publications.all() or Article.publications.all() !?

Answer (score 0):

`Publication.objects.all()` will return you all publications. But what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. Are you looking to get all Publications that have at least one Article? If so:

```
Publication.objects.exclude(article=None)
```

Comment: I want not all publications，Only be used to the Articles。

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.